# Invalid date issue in javascript parsing date function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In console, the values are rendered as

```
        var admission_date = $("#admission_date").val().trim(); < in console 14/10/2027>
        var dob_date = $("#dob").val().trim(); < in console 09/09/2017>

        var admission_date_value = new Date(admission_date); <in console invalid date>
        var dob_date_value = new Date(dob_date); <in console works okay>
```

I am not able to tackle this issue with the admission date parsing function

Comment: admission_date is getting null?

Comment: no it has value 14/10/2017

Comment: `14/10/2017` isn't a valid date in JavaScript. If you want to define a date like this you need to use `MM/DD/YYYY` format, otherwise your browser wouldn't know what to do with dates like `01/02/2000`.

Comment: Did you applied the code I have post to resolve the issue?

Comment: Format of date parsing is the issue.
It is taking 14 as month, 10 as date and 2027 as year in 14/10/2027. If you are inputting that as string, you need to change the format to mm/dd/yyyy before passing to new Date(). You need to put restriction on your textbox to allow user to enter it in one format only. Then, change it to mm/dd/yyyy format in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a very little change.

```
 var admission_date = $("#admission_date").val().trim();
 admission_date = admission_date.split("/");

 var dob_date = $("#dob").val().trim();
 dob_date = dob_date.split("/");

 var admission_date_value= new Date(admission_date[2],admission_date[1],admission_date[0]);
 var dob_date_value = new Date(dob_date[2],dob_date[1],dob_date[0]);
```